# C++: Unnitialized(?) Array on the Stack (example regarding OpenGL)

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl, stack

What is the contents of an array that is created on the stack, but has no values put in it? Like this:

```
int array[4]
cout << array[2];
```

I ask this because I have always seen in OpenGL when textures are generated, it is done like this:

```
GLuint textures[4];
glGenTextures(4, &textures[0]);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[2]);
```

What is the deal with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. The contents could be anything.  Often it's something left there by a previous function, but no guarantees are made.
2. `glGenTextures` fills in its second argument, which is passed by pointer.  Nothing is using the uninitialized value.  Just like `textures[0] = 0;`, it's overwriting whatever garbage was present.

Comment: Side note: when compiling in a debug build, the compiler may initialize the memory with some value or pattern even though it isn't required to (this is done to help point out bugs that your code may have). Don't fall in the trap of looking at memory initialized this way and thinking it's going to be the same in your release build.

Answer (score 3):

In this case the second argument to glGenTextures is a return, not an input. Basically, it fills up the textures[4] array with 4 texture ids that can be used later.

Unitialized memory is pretty much random junk leftover from previous processes/allocations. It should always be considered an error to read from an uninitialized variable before assigning a value.

Comment: In fact, even code like `volatile double x, y; x = y; x = 0.0; y = 0.0;` which looks like the final state does not depend on the initial value, actually can crash the program (e.g. when the initial value of y is a signalling NaN).

Comment: "It should always be considered an error to read from an uninitialized variable before assigning a value."

I believe it's actually UB to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The values are uninitialised, but the array is safe to use. glGenTextures fills the elements with ints that are handles to texture slots.